# Video viewing problem

Tags: 8.1, video

How can I view the videos that are stored in the phone memory of my Nokia Lumia 520 in Videos app?
I am using Windows Phone 8.1 Os if this is helpful in any way.

Comment: What's not working for you? What types of video?

Comment: I am not able to find videos in the Videos app

Comment: Have you recorded any videos or download any videos on to the phone, if so, how?

Comment: I can't view videos thats are downloaded or recorded from 520. It only show me the list of videos in sd card that I had downloaded from my old phone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft recently came out with a [file explorer for Windows Phone 8.1 called Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e).

It is pretty straightforward to use and if will show you files that don't otherwise show up in the "Video" app. You can also play videos from within the "Files" app.

You can also move files around to appropriate folders so that they show up in the "Video" app.

Answer (score 1):

- You can view videos shot by camera (.mp4) in Gallery (just like photos)
- If you want to view other formats of video you copied to your Micro SD or internal storage use 3rd party app like MoliPlayer Pro (My personal favorite).

MoliPlayer supports:

- Video - avi, mkv, mp4, h.264, rmvb, wmv, flv, ts, m2ts and vob
- Audio - aac, mp3, ape, flac and ogg

To my knowledge "Videos" app have a huge problems right now and it works fine only with movies, videos from Xbox Store. MS desperately needs to update that app. Wait for an Update or use another app - that's the only options right now

Comment: I tried. Its not helpful.

Comment: In that case there must be some OS problem, sice i use MoliPlayer Pro on my Lumia 1320 with 8.1 dev preview with no problems. You can try to do hard reset :)

Comment: I updated the question. I want to view those videos in Videos App

Comment: @VivekParekh That's a pretty different case then. To my knowledge "Videos" app have a huge problems right now and it works fine only with movies, videos from Xbox Store. MS desperately needs to update that app. Wait for an Update or use another app - that's the only options right now.

Answer (score -1):

CCPlayer is nice app for playing all format types of videos with multi screen resolution. Download it from store.

Comment: Do you have a link to the app. It would be more helpful